# Solving Coupled Non linear equation in matlab without rescaling

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to solve two coupled algebraic equation

```
f1(x,y) = 0;  
f2(x,y) = 0;
```

typical order of magnitude of the functions `f1` and `f2` are `10^42` . I ran the matlab code but it said no solution found. I figured that the problem is because scales involved is very high. Rescaling the whole equation is pretty tedious. I want to stop the root finding function `(fsolve)` when `delta(f)/f < epsilon(say 1e-6)` . How can this condition implemented in matlab? Any alternative solution to the scaling problem is also welcome.

Comment: Double precision floating-point numbers can take values of 10^42.

Answer (score 1):

RTFM (friendly of course), https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html

The options that you can provide to the solver contain the parameter `TolFun` with default value `1e-6` that is the absolute tolerance for the function value. Apparently there is no provision for relative tolerance, so you need to compute the function value scale from the initial point or more global considerations to set `TolFun = scale * epsilon`.

Comment: I tried that. It won't work if functions have different scales? e.g f1~10^32 and f2~10^14.